# LinqToLDAP string and DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, razor, ldap

My Model:

```
...
[DisplayName("Birthday")]
public DateTime extensionAttribute1 { get; set; }
```

And Controller:

```
var config = new LdapConfiguration();
        config.ConfigureFactory("DOMAIN");
        using (var context = new DirectoryContext(config))
        {
            var user =
                (from u in
                     context.Query(new ADUser(), "OU=xxx,DC=xxx", "User")
                         .Where(d => d.SAmAccountName == samaccount)

                 select new ADUser()
                 {
                     SAmAccountName = u.SAmAccountName,
                     Department = u.Department,
                     DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
                     HomePhone = u.HomePhone,
                     Mail = u.Mail,
                     Mobile = u.Mobile,
                     PostalCode = u.PostalCode,
                     StreetAddress = u.StreetAddress,
                     TelephoneNumber = u.TelephoneNumber,
                     ThumbnailPhoto = u.ThumbnailPhoto,
                     Title = u.Title,
                     l = u.l,
                     PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName = u.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,
                     extensionAttribute1 = u.extensionAttribute1
                 }).FirstOrDefault();

            return user;
        }
```

Gives the error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

How to tell that extentionAttribute1 is a DateTime?

In AD the value of extentionAttribute is "1976-08-31"

If i change the model to string it works fine but then my editorfor wont show a datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a little hint to the format to parse them back into a DateTime object.

Do this in your ADUser constructor...

```
 extensionAttribute1 = DateTime.ParseExact(u.extensionAttribute1, "yyyy-MM-dd",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```